# .NET Core 3.1 MSBuild missing libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, .net-core-3.1, musl

Until yesterday everything worked as usual. This morning I tried to open a project and I was met with such error:

```
/snap/dotnet-sdk/current/dotnet: error while loading shared libraries: libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm completely lost, nothing has changed in my system since yesterday and as such I'm wondering if there's anyone who had similar issues?

It happens both with versions `3.1.302` and `3.1.401` of .NET Core SDK.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.1 with `5.4.0-42-generic` kernel.

Comment: The 3.1.401 dotnet-sdk snap appears to be broken and it's been reported at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40739.

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong by saying that nothing has changed: .NET Core SDK snap got updated to `3.1.401`.

Reverting to a previous version (`3.1.302`) made it work. `3.1.401` still doesn't work. For some reason my IDE didn't pick it up even after changing to `3.1.302` MSBuild, had to restart it.

Leaving it here in case someone else comes across this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a temporary fix for dotnet installed via Snap.

**sudo snap revert dotnet-sdk**

SDK version v3.1.6 (SDK 3.1.302) works on Ubuntu 20.04

For "apt" installed dotnet, see webpage https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

Comment: Does someone know how to revert if you have just installed the package ? I got "cannot revert "dotnet-sdk": no revision to revert to" when I try to revert